# PHP to Python Code Differences - Arrays, Foreach Loops

Tags: php, python

I hope this question is phrased appropriately to the policies of this site.

I am trying to convert a piece of Python Code to PHP code.  I have gotten almost every function translated except I cannot figure out how Arrays and Foreach loops are different in PHP vs Python.

```
qstid = dbinputsurveyid+'X'+str(question.gid)+'X'+str(question.qid)
index=columns.index(qstid)
for i,a in enumerate(data[index]):
    if a!=None and a!='':
        answer=int(data[index][i])
        answerCodes=list(answersCode[question.qid])
        answerindex = answerCodes.index(str(answer))
        answerorder = answersOrder[question.qid][a]
        addAnswers(db, data[0][i], question.sid, question.gid, question.qid, question.type, answers[question.qid][answerindex], None,answerorder, None, None,None)
```

From some of the reading I have done. I think enumerate in python is the equivalent to a foreach loop in PHP. But im not sure how "i" and "a" come into play in the code above. They dont seem to be defined like you would in PHP.  Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Required reading: Python tutorial [section on `for` loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `i, a` in that loop gives you access to the index and values of the list.

From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

> When looping through a sequence, the position index and corresponding
>   value can be retrieved at the same time using the enumerate()
>   function.

So, in Python you'd have:

```
for i,a in enumerate( ['some', 'list'])
```

Which would be equivalent to PHP:

```
$array = ['some', 'array']; 
// Or, for PHP < 5.4: $array = array( 'some', 'array');
foreach( $array as $i => $a)
```

Comment: `$array = ['some', 'array'];` when did we get this nice, clean array syntax? ;)

Comment: PHP 5.4 adds the [new short array syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)!

Comment: "i" is just a counter - not an actual index.  It happens to correspond to the index, although enumerate's second parameter is the starting value for "i"

Comment: @nickb And safe mode, magic quotes, register globals are all gone too? I'm switching now.

Comment: @nickb For backwards compatibility, you might want to consider putting in the old array syntax. PHP 5.4 is still relatively new and may not be available to everyone, even it the server is running PHP 5.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful to understand the foreach and arrays.  

What exactly does this mean "index=columns.index(qstid)"

What do the periods and parenthesis mean in python vs php?

Comment: So in PHP the list would be some type of array?

Comment: Assuming `columns` is a list, then you're calling [`list.index(x)`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), which returns the index into the `list` that contains the value `x`, or in your case, `qstid`.

Comment: Yes, in PHP the list would become an array. Or you could use one of the [SPL data structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php), but I'd stick to the primitive types first.

Comment: @jvegas - Yes, you can use `array_search()` to achieve the same thing.